# How to check if user submit Arabic words from a form?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Is there any reliable way to check if user has entered Arabic words into a form and tries to submit it? Can Javascript handle this? Or, only server script like .NET can do this?

I'm thinking that if possible the script should directly prevent the user from inputting Arabic words into the form and show an alert pop up.

Please share any examples if you have any idea how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Add a checkbox underneath that says "Did you put Arabic words in the form?". Then check the value of the checkbox.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm having a multi-lingual website and which for English website I have a reporting form that is integrated to a ticketing system specifically for reports in English. So, I need to make sure people don't submit Arabic reports in the English form, thus to remind them to submit it from the Arabic website.

Answer (score 9):

In Unicode, Arabic characters fall in a specific range. You can use a regular expression in JavaScript to check if a string contains any characters in that range. (You could also do that in c#.) Here's a [**really helpful tool**](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block) that will let you select the ranges you want to search for and create a JS-compatible regex for that.

For example, `[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F]` will match any characters that fall in the Unicode ranges for "Arabic" and/or "Arabic Supplement".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Google Ajax Language API to detect this. Here is [an example](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Detect).